# Issue with Module Redirecting named exports

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a semi-complex Fragment using React/Styled-Components. I always try to improve the flexibility of larger Fragments/Components by exporting any sub-components that is styled so minor tweaks can easily be made anywhere in the DOM tree whenever my team need similar components.

I do this by collecting everything in an index file, and using Module Redirects as described at the end of this Mozilla article:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

However, for some reason when I try to do `export { SomeComponent, SomeOtherComponent } from './SomeStuff.styled'` or `export * from './SomeStuff.styled'` I get the error `Cannot create styled-component for component: undefined.`

What am I doing wrong?

The project is closed source so I can't show full files or a repo
All the exports in `./ListElement` are named exports.

```
// In index.js
export { default as Counter } from './Counter';
export { Element, Container, Names, Prices } from './ListElement';
export { default as OrderListHeading } from './OrderListHeading';
```

```
// In the Fragment where I'm using it
import { Counter, Element } from '.';

...

const Heading = styled(Element)``;
```

The curious thing is that it works if I import and export seperately as such:

```
// In index.js
import { Element, Container, Names, Prices } from './ListElement';

export { default as Counter } from './Counter';
export { Element, Container, Names, Prices };
export { default as OrderListHeading } from './OrderListHeading';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export { default as Counter } from './Counter';
export { Element, Container, Names, Prices } from './ListElement';
export { default as OrderListHeading } from './OrderListHeading';
```

This is not yet in current ECMAScript standard.
It's still [a proposal in stage 1](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-default-from). In order for a language feature proposal to land in the current ECMAScript standard, it must move to stage 4.

You are probably using a project configuration that doesn't support this. But if you can extend your Babel configuration you can start using this feature by installing [@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-export-default-from).

Comment: While I was not aware it's still only a stage 1 proposal - the export default module redirects are working fine.  It's the export named module redirects that doesn't work.